# Importing STK orbit file into OPNET Modeler 18.5

Tags: opnet

I need to implement a simple satellite network using both STK software (Satellite Tool Kit ) from AGI and OPNET. The satellite orbit and analysis will be designated in STK,.Next,the orbit file will be imported into OPNET.

When I import the orbit file *.sa I got the following messages.

1. Unable to convert STK file (C:\Users\UB\Documents|STK11(x64)*.sa):general failure.
2. Failed to import STK orbit file (C:\Users\UB\Documents|STK11(x64)*.sa).

   3.When I use the Topology -> Import STK Ephemerise File.

It show me a new menu for the Edit trajectory Information which I can save as a trajectory file
Any one can help me on how to create a satellite node and import these in OPNET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three types of node model:

- Fixed
- Mobile
- Satellite.

Create a new node model and in the node model editor, click `Interfaces > Node Interfaces`. In the Node Interface dialog, you can see the `Node types`. Select `yes` in a satellite node type. This will make this node as a satellite node.

Only the satellite node model can have an `Orbit` attribute where you can set the imported orbit file.